# why this float conversion exception is not well captured?

Tags: python

doing this in `Python 2.7.15`:

```
dirlist = ['lines-data', 'abgafhb', 'tmp-data.tar', '100', '115.4', '125']
for x in dirlist:
    try:
        float(x)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        dirlist.remove(x)
print dirlist
```

results in:

```
['abgafhb', '100', '115.4', '125']
```

running the `for` loop again clears out the `'abgafhb'`.

what am I missing?

P.S. tried `except` with no argument and the result is the same.

Comment: You can't modify a list that you are iterating over. It will produce the wrong results.

Comment: unless you do `for x in list(dirlist)` which creates a copy of it before starting the loop.

Comment: You'd be better off storing the ones that succeed in a new list rather than removing the ones that fail from the original list.

Comment: ops! Thank you very much!

Comment: when lines-data gets removed, abgafhb becomes the first in the list, and at the next iteration, python will go to the second element of the list (thus abgafhb is never being iterated over)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify a list you are iterating. Maybe store the successful values in a new list.

```
dir_list = ['lines-data', 'abgafhb', 'tmp-data.tar', '100', '115.4', '125']
new_list = []

for x in dir_list:
    try:
        float(x)
        new_list.append(x)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        pass

print dir_list   # will not have changed
print new_list   # will contain only strings that can be converted to float
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't like it when you modify a list you're iterating over, because then it doesn't know where it's got to and gets confused.

The easiest, though not the most efficient, way of fixing this is to iterate over a copy of the list:

```
dirlist = ['lines-data', 'abgafhb', 'tmp-data.tar', '100', '115.4', '125']
for x in dirlist[:]:  # Note the [:]
    try:
        float(x)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        dirlist.remove(x)
print dirlist
```

Comment: what would be the most efficient?

Comment: @asdf1234 Ralf's answer would be _more_ efficient; I don't know about _most_. If you want _most_ efficient, though, you'll want the C programming language (warning: you need epic skillz for C!).